# arch linux: sublime text text not alligned vertically

Tags: arch-linux, sublime-text-2

so instead of my code being vertically aligned like usual and in any other code text editor it has weird vertical alignment like i am typing in Microsoft Word or something. anyone have an idea what this could be?

ps its a fresh install not me messing up some unknown setting

[image]

**EDIT**: **solution** i forgot to install a default font library during my arch linux install, if you have this problem, do [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/general_recommendations#Fonts) and restart your X server

Comment: A picture would be extraordinarily helpful. Additionally, I would **strongly** suggest using [Sublime Text 3](https://sublimetext.com/3) instead. All development work is now focused on ST3 - [*`"I don't know of any good reason to not use Sublime Text 3"`*](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-2-not-developed-anymore/18680/4) - Will Bond, ST core developer. Additionally, ST2 is [no longer the default download](https://sublimetext.com). ST3 has many bug fixes over 2, so this may not even be an issue once you upgrade.

Comment: thanks for the reccomendation, but nothing changed. text ist still lined up like Word text

Comment: The profanity is not necessary.

Comment: uuu... i meant no harm, surprised its a big deal

Comment: @user2255757 It may or may not be a big deal to you, but it is completely unnecessary. You could have made an example that wouldn't offend anybody. Unfortunately I can't clean up without removing all meaning from your post. Note that other users may flag your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: You haven't explained what you think is wrong with your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot to install a default font library during my arch linux install, if you have this problem, do [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/general_recommendations#Fonts) and restart your X server

Answer (score 1):

Since your screenshot doesn't illustrate any *obvious* problems, I'm going to *assume* using a variable-width font is giving you troubles. Commonly,  monospaced fonts are used for coding.

> A monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width, or non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each occupy the same amount of horizontal space. This contrasts with variable-width fonts, where the letters and spacings have different widths. –[Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Monospaced_font)

Popular examples for monospaced fonts are [Fira Mono](https://github.com/mozilla/Fira), [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro), [Inconsolata](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html), or system-default fonts like Courier New, Lucida Console (both Windows), Monaco (Mac OS X), or Ubuntu Mono (Ubuntu Linux).

You can change the font in your user settings (`Preferences > Settings`, or *“Preferences: Settings”* from the [command palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html)).

**Example**:

```
{
  "font_face": "Fira Mono"
}
```

Comment: hey thanks yes mono-space is what i am looking for. didn't know the terminology for it. changing the settings according to your specifications didn' fix the problem though. they are still variable spaced.

Comment: @user2255757 Interesting. Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: my apologies, I forgot to install a default font library during my fresh arch linux install. never forgot that before so it seemed like an alien problem. thank you for taking the time to try and help me though :)