# Fix Alignment of Split Terminal Panes

Tags: tmux, google-chrome-os, linux-terminal

Essentially, it seems that any kind of split within terminal becomes unaligned. I'm using tmux below to demonstrate the problem, but it also occurs when I make split panes using NERDTree with vim. This is problematic because it makes the cursor pointer hard to read. I'm using linux beta for ChromeOS. How can I fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The arrow in prompts on the left is wider than any other character. Your problem may be very similar to [this issue](https://superuser.com/q/1118967/432690). Please see if the answers there advance your research.

Answer (score 1):

I use [the same Oh My Zsh theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme), by the looks of it, and have the same issue. As Kamil Maciorowski says, the ➜ character in the prompt is double-width, and hterm (the Web terminal emulator used in the ChromeOS terminal) seems to have a problem with that (see https://crbug.com/939084).

In the meantime, replacing that character in your prompt with something else will work around the issue. In our case (with the Oh My Zsh theme), I changed the first line of ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme to use `->` instead:

```bsh
# Old line: local ret_status="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"
local ret_status="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}-> :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"
PROMPT='${ret_status} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'
```